# regular expression to find meta value

Tags: java, regex

i am trying to read from a webpage and get the last modified date from meta. for example

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta http-equiv="last-modified" content="Mon, 17 Sep 2012 13:57:35 SGT" />
</head>
```

i am reading line by line, how can i build the regex in this case? I am fairly new to the regex. i have tried

```
line.matches("<meta http-equiv=\"last-modified\" content=\"(\w)*\" /> ");
```

but do not think it is correct.

Comment: Usually people will say regex is not the right tool for HTML, but in this case, there should be no nested tags, so it should be fine. `/\<meta.*?http-equiv=\"last-modified\".*?content=\"([^\"]+).*?\>/` something like that.

Comment: b) [Parsing HTML is not a task for regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Don't use regex as it is an overkill for this job. Just find the matching tag, and read after `content="`

Comment: line.matches("<meta http-equiv=\"last-modified\" content=\"(\w)*\" />
");

Comment: @Orbling the attributes could still be in a different order. And you can't be sure that the tags will always be on their own line.

Comment: It's fine in this case to use regex, it's just plucking attributes out of a tag.

Comment: @user1275129 please edit that into the question

Comment: @m.buettner: The attributes being in alternate order can be handled if needed. The content might be in a regular layout anyhow.

Comment: hi iccthedral, how can i do that... i am clueless atm

Comment: Sure... as can be lots of things in HTML. I'm usually the first one to check out whether a **specific** HTML problem can't be solved with regex. But still it's fair to note, that a 100% working version with regex isn't as easy as you'd think at first glance.

Comment: @m.buettner: Aye, which is why I caveated my comment with "in this case", regex is frequently not the best candidate for this sort of task.  But parsing a full DOM structure can be overkill too.

Comment: @user1275129: the problem with your attempt is, that \w only matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` ... but you also need `,:` and whitespace

Comment: i will try to adjust now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you should [never use regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la), if you insist upon it, [heres a regex](http://regexr.com?329sr) option

```
Pattern metaPattern = Pattern.compile("meta .*\"last-modified\" content="(.*)");
Matcher metaMatch = metaPattern.matcher(sampleString);
if metaMatch.matches()
{
    System.out.println(metaMatch.group(1));
}
```

Comment: ty, i also found out this             String metaRegex="<meta.*?http-equiv=\"last-modified\".*?content=\"([^\"]+).*?>";
               final Pattern metapa = Pattern.compile(metaRegex, Pattern.DOTALL);  
               final Matcher metamatch = metapa.matcher(html);  

               String lastmodified=null;
if (metamatch.find()) {
 lastmodified=metamatch.group(1);
}

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `\w` only for your group, since your target information contains *non*-word characters.

Try something like:

```
String line = "<meta http-equiv=\"last-modified\" content=\"Mon, 17 Sep 2012 13:57:35 SGT\" />";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<meta .*last-modified.*content=\"(.*)\".*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if (m.matches())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Output:

```
Mon, 17 Sep 2012 13:57:35 SGT
```

Comment: Even if he only gets one line at a time, you should probably make that `.*` ungreedy.

Comment: ty, because Tadgh answered earlier, so i picked his, but your answer is good too

Answer (score 0):

And here's a solution with no regex.

Of course, you would have to be careful using this and do some checks beforehand.

```
String data = "<head>" +  
              "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1252\">" +
              "<meta http-equiv=\"last-modified\" content=\"Mon, 17 Sep 2012 13:57:35 SGT\" />" + 
              "</head>";

String key =  "<meta http-equiv=\"last-modified\" content=\"";

int from = data.lastIndexOf(key);
String tag = data.substring(from + key.length());
int to = tag.indexOf("\"");
String date = tag.substring(0, to);
System.out.println(date);
```